# Unable to install 3rd party pluging using ES + Kibana 7.6.0

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm stuck in the situation where I'm to run a plugin which only support ES/Kibana 7.6.0 version, so I installed and run both services and they are working as expected. Problem comes when I attempt to install the plugin using the command

> /usr/share/kibana/bin/./kibana-plugin install ​file​:​///PATH_TO_FILE/sigma-ui-xxxxx.zip

> and I get error as
> "Kibana should not be run as root.  Use --allow-root to continue."

Further I attempt to edit elasticsearch bin file and added

> if ! echo $* | grep -E '(^-d |-d$| -d |--daemonize$|--daemonize )' > /dev/null; then
> exec 
> "$JAVA" 
> $ES_JAVA_OPTS 
> -Des.path.home="$ES_HOME" 
> -Des.path.conf="$ES_PATH_CONF" 
> -Des.distribution.flavor="$ES_DISTRIBUTION_FLAVOR" 
> -Des.distribution.type="$ES_DISTRIBUTION_TYPE" 
> -Des.bundled_jdk="$ES_BUNDLED_JDK" 
> -cp "$ES_CLASSPATH" 
> **-Des.insecure.allow.root=true **
> org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch 
> "$@"
> else
> exec 
> "$JAVA" 
> $ES_JAVA_OPTS 
> -Des.path.home="$ES_HOME" 
> -Des.path.conf="$ES_PATH_CONF" 
> -Des.distribution.flavor="$ES_DISTRIBUTION_FLAVOR" 
> -Des.distribution.type="$ES_DISTRIBUTION_TYPE" 
> -Des.bundled_jdk="$ES_BUNDLED_JDK" 
> -cp "$ES_CLASSPATH" 
> **-Des.insecure.allow.root=true **
> org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch 
> "$@" 
> <&- &

but adding **-Des.insecure.allow.root=true **" didn't helped me as I'm still getting same errors, here are different combination I tried in order to install the plugin all returning with errors, I appreciate if someone can guide me overcome this issue. Thank you.

```
asad@elk:~$ /usr/share/kibana/bin/./kibana-plugin install file:///home/asad/sigma_ui_1.2.5.zip
Found previous install attempt. Deleting...
Babel could not write cache to file: /usr/share/kibana/optimize/.babel_register_cache.json 
due to a permission issue. Cache is disabled.
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Cannot delete files/directories outside the current working directory. Can be overridden with the `force` option."
```